# Is there an English word that means 'a program that calculates premiums based on age, and some sum insured'

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for the english equivalent of the word "cotizador". I wasn't able to find it. Hope you can help me.

Comment: The common  translation dictionaries give is : ***quoter*** from to quote: state, calculate the price/value of something.

Comment: "Rate finder " is out there.

Comment: Try 'rate calculator', or more generally, 'actuarial table'.

Comment: I first thought of actuarial table too, but upon doing some research, I found it was mostly used for those charts that tell how much longer you're likely to live at any given age.

Comment: @StevenLittman ...but isn't that in essence what is needed to do what is asked for in the title?

Answer (score 1):

Just call it a *premium calculator*.

It ultimately uses actuarial tables (or a rate table based on them) which give a rate per thousand. Then it scales that up to correspond to the actual policy amount, yielding the premium.